# Number digits with scientific notations changed after converted to characters

Tags: r, scientific-notation

I find the digits of numbers with scientific notations will be changed after converted to character:

```
options(scipen=-20,digits=5);
asd <- c(1957011319,1274863277)
as.numeric(asd)
[1] 1.9570e+09 1.2749e+09
```

After convertion:

```
as.character(as.numeric(asd))
[1] "1.957011319e+09" "1.274863277e+09"
```

How could I keep the digits in character formats?

Comment: See what happens with `options(scipen=-20,digits=20)`. It is just a matter of display.

Comment: @Pascal I agree.  Internally, R has its own representation and what you see is simply how it gets displayed.  By the way, it isn't clear from your question what you want.

Comment: Actually I want to make tests in the figure. `text(x=...,y=...,lables=XXX)`, when I input the number in text(), the digits of the output changed (1.9570e+09 vs "1.957011319e+09"). So how could I keep this digit?

Comment: Use `format` or `prettyNum` or one of the other formating functions.